# Is there a document editor with revision control

Tags: software-recommendation, editor, document

I'm looking for a document editor (or software) that 'create a revision' every time a file saves (if there are changes). It's preferred to show the difference in a nice way. Something like a combination of 'automatic backup s/w' + `meld` difference viewer.

Online example is askubuntu's revision.   ([Example](https://askubuntu.com/posts/28086/revisions))

Answer (score 1):

Two come to mind:

- Emacs
- Anjuta

More detailed answer:

[From the Emacs manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html):

> **28.1 Version Control**
>
> A version control system is a program that can record multiple versions of a source file, storing information such as the creation time of each version, who made it, and a description of what was changed.
>
> The Emacs version control interface is called VC. VC commands work with several different version control systems; **currently, it supports GNU Arch, Bazaar, CVS, Git, Mercurial, Monotone, RCS, SCCS/CSSC, and Subversion. Of these, the GNU project distributes CVS, Arch, RCS, and Bazaar**.
>
> VC is enabled automatically whenever you visit a file governed by a version control system. To disable VC entirely, set the customizable variable `vc-handled-backends` to nil (see [Customizing VC](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Customizing-VC.html#Customizing-VC)).

---

[From the Anjuta features list](https://projects.gnome.org/anjuta/features.html):

> In addition, the file manager context menu also lists actions associated with other plugins, such as build actions (associated with the build system plugin), CVS/Subversion actions (associated with version control system plugins) and project actions (associated with the project manager plugin). This allows you to conveniently perform all actions from within the file manager.

[GIT plugin](https://wiki.gnome.org/Anjuta/Roadmap/GitPlugin) for Anjuta.